# Disable block mining reward in private testnet

Tags: private-blockchain, testnets, genesis, block-reward

Is there a way I can disable the generation of block reward in a private network during creation? Any parameter in genesis.json can do so?

Comment: You can remove 'alloc' param in `genesis.json` file.

Comment: @BinGoBinBin I do not think that is correct, 'alloc' is to define a list of pre-filled wallets. What I am looking for is a way to remove the mining reward, so the volume of eth will not increase over time.

Comment: I know what you want, please wait for me ten minutes to test. HaHaHa~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change source file [consensus](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/consensus.go) to implement. As follows:

1. clone [go-ethereum] source file
2. open consensus/ethash/consensus.go file, then find AccumulateRewards function and annotation tow lines. The result is

   `func AccumulateRewards(state *state.StateDB, header *types.Header, uncles []*types.Header) {
     reward := new(big.Int).Set(blockReward)
     r := new(big.Int)
     for _, uncle := range uncles {
       r.Add(uncle.Number, big8)
       r.Sub(r, header.Number)
       r.Mul(r, blockReward)
       r.Div(r, big8)
       //state.AddBalance(uncle.Coinbase, r)
       r.Div(blockReward, big32)
       reward.Add(reward, r)
     }
     //state.AddBalance(header.Coinbase, reward)
   }`
3. Rebuild. executing `make all` command and then run `geth`.

Now, you can start mine, all rewards wouldn't be added account balance of coinbase.

Hope it helps ~

Comment: Thanks @BinGoBinBin! So there is no way i can disable it without changing the source?

Comment: As far as know, there is no way~