# Where and how can I set the mining reward?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I have been searching for a way to reduce the eth reward on a private deployment from 3 to 1.  The best source I have 
( [Disable block mining reward in private testnet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23877/disable-block-mining-reward-in-private-testnet) ) is to comment out the miner reward line so that no reward is given to the miner.

How can I set the miner reward to 1 and where does the 3 ETH reward get set?

It got me thinking, what is stopping someone modifying this function to say reward + 1000, recompile and rejoin the network.

```
func AccumulateRewards(state *state.StateDB, header *types.Header, uncles 
[]*types.Header) {
reward := new(big.Int).Set(blockReward)
r := new(big.Int)
for _, uncle := range uncles {
r.Add(uncle.Number, big8)
r.Sub(r, header.Number)
r.Mul(r, blockReward)
r.Div(r, big8)
//state.AddBalance(uncle.Coinbase, r)
r.Div(blockReward, big32)
reward.Add(reward, r)
}
 //state.AddBalance(header.Coinbase, reward)
}
```

Comment: Nothing is stopping anyone from modifying rewards , and if you convince all miners to run your code, it is going to happen. otherwise, your node will be out of sync from the blockchain

Comment: I'd assumed the question referred to a private chain, but yes, agree with this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I set the miner reward to 1 and where does the 3 ETH reward get set?

The value you're looking for is in [`consensus.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/885c13c2c941710f5545bee01541e6f7602599aa/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L38):

```
// Ethash proof-of-work protocol constants.
var (
    frontierBlockReward  *big.Int = big.NewInt(5e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block
    byzantiumBlockReward *big.Int = big.NewInt(3e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block upward from Byzantium
    maxUncles                     = 2                 // Maximum number of uncles allowed in a single block
)
```

You're specifically looking for `byzantiumBlockReward`. Set it to `big.NewInt(1e+18)`.

This doesn't change the rewards incurred for [uncle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-an-uncle-ommer-block) blocks, though I *think* changing `maxUncles` to `0` would suffice, should you want to do that.